# Deploy Java web application war file in domain

Tags: java, web-applications, dns, subdomain, appdomain

I developed a java web application and generated 2 different enviroment war files names as test.war and prod.war file.

I want to publish the war file in the domain. so i bought the domain. for ex:- www.example.com

and I want to publish my war files in domain as "www.test.example.com" and www.prod.example.com ". Is this possible to do this ?

Comment: Well, sort of.  Do you have a server?  Does the domain name point to the server's IP address?

Comment: I have a tomcat server and installed in machine and that have a main domain name for ex: example.com

Comment: OK, something needs to tell the external world what the IP address of "www.test.example.com" is.  Normally you set that up with your registrar, or you run a domain name server yourself on example.com and it tells people where to find "www.test".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You has bought the last part `domain.com` , then you need to configure DNS to point `www.test.example.com`  and `www.prod.example.com` to an IP of a machine owned by you (you can have one machine for each domain).

If you have tomcat then you can deploy two virtual hosts, each one responding to a domain, with its own war deployment

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.test.example.com">

  <Host name="www.test.example.com"  appBase="test"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  </Host>

  <Host name="www.prod.example.com"  appBase="prod"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Alias>example.com</Alias>
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Comment: Most servers besides Tomcat support virtual hosting.  You just have to add a bit of configuration to tell the server that your two web apps run on different server names (not necessarily the one you're actually running on).

Comment: I like your example config file.  Is the `<Alias>` under "www.prod" there just as an example of how to use an alias, or is there some special reason for it?

Comment: I was editing!, thanks. Ravikanth said it has a main domain _example.com_ Using this alias allows to use the virtual host to map `www.prod.example.com` and `http://example.com`. Any other access with a different DNS will be served by `www.test.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Domain is public address which has a public IP.First purchase a platform in which jvm and application container should be available.After that you can configure your deployment descriptor for sub domain