# Deploy WAR file in a external domain using Tomcat

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, server, permission-denied

Thanks to read me and try to help me :)

I am fighting this problem for many days ... I have a WAR file that I want to implement in an external domain using Tomcat.

I have been reading some examples like this:
[Similar Problem in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839278/deploy-java-web-application-war-file-in-domain)
But this doesn't work for me.

I have changed the port to 80 and added this:

```
<Host name="www.extremadurainv.unex.es" appBase="webapps"
 unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" 
 xmlNamespaceAware="false"> 
<Alias>extremadurainv.unex.es/spinav</Alias>
</host>
```

But when I try to access in the webpage I have the following error:

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /spinav on this
> server.

So, do I have to change something in the Apache server? Or is it just a Tomcat problem?

Thank so much for your attention!

Comment: "/spinav" cannot be part of the host name (nor the alias) . Is www.extremadurainv.unex.es declared locally (if you do nslookup, does it answer your server) ?

Comment: Hi @EugèneAdell, Sorry the first was a mistake, is edited. if I do "nslookup extremadurainv.unex.es/spinav" I have the following answer: Server: "correct server" Address: "Correct answer" **server can't find extremadurainv.unex.es/spinav: NXDOMAIN ...

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux ? Please check and update your tags accordingly to give more attention from SO experts.

Comment: On Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS). What's tags do you recommend me? Thank you again Eugéne!

Comment: for example, remove apache/web/server, add ubuntu/permission-denied